# The matrix of rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations

Melvin Schwartz starts [Principles of Electrodynamics](http://www.kilibro.com/book/preview/4894_principles-of-electrodynamics) by matrix of rotations, on page 4:

[image]

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_operator_%28vector_space%29) says something similar but less thoroughly, so I will not discuss it.

Basically, page says that we can translate basis vectors

$$\begin{bmatrix}i\\j\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} i' + a_{21} j' \\a_{12} i' + a_{22} j'\end{bmatrix}$$

and, it is obvious that

$i\cdot i' = a_{11}$

$i\cdot j' = a_{21}$

$j\cdot i' = a_{12}$

$ j \cdot j' = a_{22}$

Why obvious? where does this come from?

Ok, let me exploit this fact and replace the matrix A coefficients with these elementary vector products:

$$\begin{bmatrix}i\\j\end{bmatrix} 
= \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} i' + a_{21} j' \\a_{12} i' + a_{22} j'\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{21} \\a_{12} & a_{22} \end{bmatrix} \ \ \begin{bmatrix} i' \\ j' \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} i\cdot i' & i\cdot j' \\j\cdot i' & j \cdot j' \end{bmatrix} \ \begin{bmatrix} i' \\ j' \end{bmatrix} 
= \begin{bmatrix}i\\j\end{bmatrix} \ \begin{bmatrix}i' & j'\end{bmatrix}  \ \begin{bmatrix} i' \\ j' \end{bmatrix} 
= A \ \begin{bmatrix} i' \\ j' \end{bmatrix} $$

This looks very nice, with one problem when I do a check

$$\begin{bmatrix}i\\j\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}i\\j\end{bmatrix} \ \begin{bmatrix}i' & j'\end{bmatrix}  \ \begin{bmatrix} i' \\ j' \end{bmatrix} 
= \begin{bmatrix}i\\j\end{bmatrix} \ \begin{bmatrix}i'\cdot i' + j' \cdot j'\end{bmatrix}   
= \begin{bmatrix}i\\j\end{bmatrix} \ \begin{bmatrix}1+1\end{bmatrix} 
= \mathbf{2} \ \begin{bmatrix}i\\j\end{bmatrix} \neq \begin{bmatrix}i\\j\end{bmatrix}
$$

Do you see that factor of two has appeared? Where is the mistake?

Comment: It's not obvious unless you know that the $i',j'$ and $k'$ form an orthonormal basis.

Comment: I you look at the page, the orthnormality is introduced only in the end, after the point that I address in the question. So, might be it is not even important (for the obviousness, claimed in the very beginning).

Comment: Maybe that's what the text says, but it had to be assumed before. If both the $i,j,k$ and the $i',j',k'$ are bases, then the matrix $A$ transforming one into the other must be invertible. On the other hand they say the matrix of scalar products of pairs from the different bases is also matrix $A$. A little bit of algebra proves that this is only possible if the $i',j',k'$ form an orthonormal basis.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that matrix is the same A? Nowhere I see $A^T = A$. For orthnormal matrices it must be that $A^{-1} = A^T$. And, this is what page says. But, it says it in the end. Invertibility is not my question. I want to know why $\vec i \vec i = 1$ and $\vec j \vec j = 1$ and $\vec i \vec i + \vec j \vec j = 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your notation makes it look as if $i$, $j$ etc. were numbers. It's clear from the book's notation that they are in fact vectors. Thus your manipulations treating them as numbers are faulty. You can use the sort of notation that you're using if you know what you're doing; but then you have to keep track of which vectors are row vectors and which are column vectors. If you do that, you find that where you have $\hat i'\cdot\hat i'+\hat j'\cdot\hat j'$ you should have $\hat i'\hat i'^\top+\hat j'\hat j'^\top$, the sum of the projectors onto the two orthonormal vectors, and that sum is indeed the identity as required.

The equations $\hat i\cdot\hat i'=a_{11}$ etc. are obtained by multiplying equations (1-2-1) through by $\hat i$, $\hat j$ and $\hat k$ and using the orthonormality of $\hat i'$, $\hat j'$ and $\hat k'$.

[*Edit following up on the exchange in the comments:*]

Here's a complete rendition of a working version of your "check":

\begin{align}
\def\i{\hat i}
\def\j{\hat j}
\pmatrix{\i&\j}
&=
\pmatrix{a_{11}\i'+a_{21}\j'&a_{12}\i'+a_{22}\j'}
\\
&=
\pmatrix {\i'&\j'}\pmatrix{a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}}
\\
&=
\pmatrix {\i'&\j'}\pmatrix{\i'^\top\i&\i'^\top\j\\\j'^\top\i&\j'^\top\j}
\\
&=
\pmatrix {\i'&\j'}\left[\pmatrix{\i'^\top\\\j'^\top}\pmatrix{\i&\j}\right]
\\
&=
\left[\pmatrix {\i'&\j'}\pmatrix{\i'^\top\\\j'^\top}\right]\pmatrix{\i&\j}
\\
&=
\left[\i'\i^\top+\j'\j'^\top\right]\pmatrix{\i&\j}
\\
&=\pmatrix{\i&\j}\;.
\end{align}

You can also transpose the whole thing, but then you have to make sure to transpose everything on both levels, both the vectors $\i$ etc. and the vectors containing them. The problem with your version is that it's a mixture of the two, where you transposed the outer vectors but not the vectors $\i$ etc., and then the multiplications aren't well-defined.

Comment: This is a brilliant guess but Why do you say that there is no context, after I referred the book and why does the book says afterwards that $j \cdot j = 1$?

Comment: @Val: I wasn't aware that you were addressing your question only to people who have access to that book. The link you provided to the book doesn't work for me ("Server Error"). Now that you've included the image, it turns out that you had completely misrepresented the equations, and my answer has become irrelevant.

Comment: $\hat i \cdot \hat i' = a_{11}$ is derived from (1-2-1), so $\hat i \cdot \hat i' = 1$ cannot be derived from (1-2-1) also. Ok? Also, I do not understand how $\hat i' \cdot \hat i'^T$ can change the things. It must equal 1 for the purposes of othonormality. Orthonormal vectors times themselves give 1. This is what orthonormality means. I do not understand why sum of two such products will give you 1 rather than 2.

Comment: So, I do not see how hats improve the situations. They only did worse.

Comment: @Val: Hats improve the situation in so far as they tell us and remind you that these are vectors. Would you have manipulated them like numbers if you'd left the hats on?

Comment: But, do you see the problems with your new answer that I've pointed out? $i$ is orthonormal with itself. It cannot be orthonormal with $i'$. Why do you say the opposite?

Comment: @Val: My apologies, both for overlooking your first comment and replying only to the second, and for the typo; it should have said $\hat i \cdot\hat i'=a_{11}$, not $\hat i \cdot\hat i'=1$. Regarding $\hat i'\cdot\hat i'^T$: That notation makes no sense, at least not if you're using the dot as the book is using it, to denote the dot product between two vectors; there's no dot product between a row vector and a column vector. What I wrote was $\hat i'\hat i'^\top$, where the juxtaposition implies matrix multiplication. The result is not a number but a projection matrix.

Comment: To see explicitly why $\hat i\cdot\hat{i'} = a_{11}$, expand out the $\hat i$ on the left: $\hat i\cdot\hat{i'}$ $= (a_{11}\hat{i'}+a_{21}\hat{j'}+a_{31}\hat{k'})\cdot\hat{i'}$ $=a_{11}(\hat{i'}\cdot\hat{i'})+a_{21}(\hat{j'}\cdot\hat{i'})+a_{31}(\hat{k'}\cdot\hat{i'})$ $=a_{11}(1)+a_{21}(0)+a_{31}(0) = a_{11}$.

Comment: Ok, you have fixed $i \cdot i' = 1$ to $i \cdot i' = a_{11}$. But, original question was why $i \cdot i^T + j \cdot j^T = 1+1 = 1$? You say it is because of orthonormality. But, how can 1+1=2 be 1+1=1?

Comment: The problem is that what you've written in your 'check' doesn't work because the quantities $\hat{i}, \hat{i'},$ etc. are not _scalar_ quantities, and so you specifically can't go from the matrix $((i.i'\ i.j')\ (j.i'\ j.j'))$ to the product of two 'vectors' $(i,j)^T$ and $(i',j')$ because the latter aren't actually vectors at all.

Comment: @Val: OK, now it's getting complicated :-) Please keep apart my replies and Steven's replies, because we're partly saying different things. In your last comment, you again placed a dot, presumably denoting a dot product, between $i$ and $i^T$. I had just explained why that doesn't make sense. (You also left off the primes this time; I'm assuming that was just a typo.) What I wrote (please take it exactly as I write it) was $\hat i'\hat i'^\top+\hat j'\hat j'^\top$. If you write that out, you'll see that it's the sum of two $2\times2$ matrices. Neither of them is the identity, but their sum is.

Comment: @joriki: can you write this down in the matrix form? Can I multiply column <i,j> by the identity matrix? I see how $I \ [i,j]^T = [i,j]^T$ but not how to do it in opposite order, $[i,j]^T \ I$. But I see how summing n units in diagonal can give me 1. This seems to be the key.

Comment: @Val: OK, I'll also drop the primes and hats from now on to simplify the notation and so we don't have to switch back and forth between your comments and mine. As an example, take the orthonormal vectors

$$i=\frac15\pmatrix{3\\4}$$

and

$$j=\frac15\pmatrix{4\\-3}\;.$$

Then

$$
ii^T=\frac1{25}\pmatrix{3\\4}\pmatrix{3&4}=\frac1{25}\pmatrix{9&12\\12&16}
$$

and

$$
jj^T=\frac1{25}\pmatrix{4\\-3}\pmatrix{4&-3}=\frac1{25}\pmatrix{16&-12\\-12&16}\;,
$$

and the sum is the identity.

Comment: @Val: I added a complete corrected version of your "check" to the answer. I hope that helps clear things up.